# How to get camera focal length with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I work on a project that I need the focal length to calculate the distance from the image. so is there any way to get is automatically form camera properties

Answer (score 5):

You can calibrate your camera using OpenCV. See [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html) tutorial for details. As a result you'll get the camera matrix in the form of

```
fx 0 cx
0 fy cy
0  0 1
```

where:

`fx`, `fy` focal length of the camera in x and y direction in **pixels**

`cx`, `cy` principal point (the point that all rays converge) coordinates in **pixels**

then if you know the physical diameters of the sensor you can call `calibrationMatrixValues` [function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga87955f4330d5c20e392b265b7f92f691) to get focal length of the camera in real world units (e.g. millimeters).

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to do camera calibration which is not easy but well documented.
https://learnopencv.com/camera-calibration-using-opencv/

In the past I have used a [desktop-application by BoofCV](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Applications#Camera_Calibration).
Tutorial Camera Calibration - BoofCV

The tutorial will guide you step by step.
It involves:

Downloading their app.
printing a checkerboard and sticking it on a hard surface which is fun.
Following the calibration process.
Remember: this has to be done only once (for each camera).